# Spring constructor injection in bean. Is it a bean anymore?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am learning spring framework and have a very basic question. I tried to find the answer, but couldn't find it, so bear with me. I have seen the following kind of wiring(it that is what it is called) in spring.

```
public class A {

    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}


public class B {

    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

So I understand that this autowiring is done using constructor injection. Then in the `context.xml` I have the following

```
    <bean id="a" class="A" autowire="constructor">
    </bean>

    <bean id="b" class="B" >
        <property name="foo" value="foo1" />
    </bean>
```

(I am learning the configuration using annotation rather than `context.xml`, but using it here since it seems to provide a more clear picture). So my question is, since a bean, by definition, should have only no-args constructors and getters and setters, doesn't doing a constructor injection, disqualify it from being a bean? What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: Bean configuration shouldn't be in web.xml. It should be in spring configuration xml

Comment: @Keerthivasan sorry, that was my mistake. I will correct it.

Comment: Please check out this link.http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-properties-detailed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bean` is a loaded term. While the **JavaBean** specification did at least at one point require a no-args constructor, this does not mean **Spring beans** do.

Comment: so even `JavaBean` doesn't necessarily require a no-args constructor anymore? Thank you for clearing the ambiguity.

Comment: Well I haven't been paying too much attention on the recent developments on JavaBeans, but  SpringBeans and JavaBeans are not the same thing, regardless of the similar Beans suffix.